# Best way to group filename based on filename in Bash?

Tags: bash, csv, for-loop, awk, uniq

I have a folder with the following files:

```
DA-001-car.jpg
DA-001-dog.jpg
DA-001-coffee.jpg
DA-002-house.jpg
DA-003-coffee.jpg
DA-003-cat.jpg
...
```

I want to generate this (CSV) output:

```
SKU, IMAGE
DA-001, "DA-001-car.jpg, DA-001-dog.jpg, DA-001-coffee.jpg"
DA-002, "DA-001-house.jpg"
DA-003, "DA-001-coffee.jpg, DA-001-cat.jpg"
```

I tried to program this in Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "SKU, FILE" >> tmp.csv
for file in /home/calvin/test/*.jpg
do
    SKU_NAME="${file##*/}"
    echo ${SKU_NAME:0:6}, \"inner for-loop?, ?, ?\" >> tmp.csv
done
uniq tmp.csv output.csv
```

As you can see I'm a noob as for programming :)
Please help me out, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

This will do the trick. This requires GNU `awk` to output in ascending order. If you don't care about the order, you can use any old `awk` and remove the `PROCINFO` line

```
#!/bin/bash

awk -F- '
  BEGIN{
    print "SKU, IMAGE"
  }
  {
    sep=!a[$2]?"":", "
    a[$2]=a[$2] sep $0
  }
  END{
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc" # GNU only feature
    for(i in a){print "DA-" i ", " "\"" a[i] "\""}
  }' <(find /home/calvin/test -type f -name "*.jpg" -printf "%f\n") > ./tmp.csv
```

#### Example Output

```
$ cat ./tmp.csv
SKU, IMAGE
DA-001, "DA-001-coffee.jpg, DA-001-car.jpg, DA-001-dog.jpg"
DA-002, "DA-002-house.jpg"
DA-003, "DA-003-coffee.jpg, DA-003-cat.jpg"
```

Comment: The output is only:
SKU, IMAGE

Comment: Does `find /home/calvin/test -type f -name "*.jpg" -printf "%f\n"` output a list of jpg files?

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
        OFS = ", "
        print "SKU", "IMAGE"
        for (i=1; i<ARGC; i++) {
            curr = fname = ARGV[i]
            sub(/-[^-]+$/,"",curr)
            if ( curr != prev ) {
                if ( i > 1 ) {
                    print prev, "\"" fnames "\""
                }
                prev = curr
                fnames = ""
            }
            fnames = (fnames == "" ? "" : fnames OFS) fname
        }
        print prev, "\"" fnames "\""
        exit
    }
' /home/calvin/test/*.jpg
SKU, IMAGE
DA-001, "DA-001-car.jpg, DA-001-coffee.jpg, DA-001-dog.jpg"
DA-002, "DA-002-house.jpg"
DA-003, "DA-003-cat.jpg, DA-003-coffee.jpg"
```

Comment: Is there a way without using awk. But just using Bash with for-loop or while? So that I can easily ./run.sh

Comment: Doing any text manipulation is simpler, more robust, faster to execute, and more portable in awk than in a shell script. Wanting to run it as `./run.sh` doesn't mean you can't use awk. Instead of saving the awk script in a file and running it as `awk -f that_script_file *.jpg` just put the script inside single quotes and run it as `awk 'that_script' *.jpg`. I updated my answer to do that.

Answer (score 1):

If the filenames don't contain spaces, you can use sed instead of an inner loop:

```
printf '%s\n' *.jpg \
| cut -f1,2 -d- \
| sort -u \
| while IFS= read -r sku ; do
    echo "$sku",\"$(echo "$sku"* | sed 's/ /, /')\"
done
```

With the inner loop, you can switch to `printf` from `echo`. Sed is used to remove the trailing comma.

```
printf '%s\n' *.jpg \
| cut -f1,2 -d- \
| sort -u \
| while IFS= read -r sku ; do
    printf %s "$sku, \""
    for f in "$sku"* ; do
        printf '%s, ' "$f"
    done | sed 's/, $//'
    printf '"\n'
done
```

If you don't want to parse the output of `ls` and run `sort`, you can store the prefixes in an associative array:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A prefix
for jpg in *.jpg ; do
    p1=${jpg%%-*}
    jpg=${jpg#*-}
    p2=${jpg%%-*}
    prefix[$p1-$p2]=1
done

for sku in "${!prefix[@]}" ; do
    printf '%s, "' "$sku"
    for f in "$sku"* ; do
        printf '%s, ' "$f"
    done | sed 's/, $//'
    printf '"\n'
done
```

Comment: When I run your first code, there is no comma between DA-001-coffee.jpg and DA-001-dog.jpg

Answer (score 0):

As result of all the replies and advises I'm using this code to achieve the desired output:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "SKU, IMAGES" >> output.csv

ls *.jpg | cut -f1,2 -d- | sort -u | while read SKU
do
    echo $SKU, \"$(echo "$SKU"* | sed 's/ /, /g')\" >> output.csv
done
```

Thanks all!

Comment: That literally contains more bugs than lines of code and is very inefficient so you should reconsider. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice), https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes, and https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs for some, but not all, of the issues (e.g. one extra issue is it'll include non-jpg files in the output that just happen to match the start of any of the jpg files you input).

Comment: You should run all your scripts through http://shellcheck.net until you get some familiarity with shell programming as that'd at least tell you about the common, fundamental errors.